# How to add column in django user table and access it directly from admin page?

Tags: python, django

I have seen many answers to this question but none worked out.

```
class userLogin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isManager = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have executed the commands `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations`.

The commands were executed successfully. I got an ok and change log in the terminal.

If I click on add user on the admin page I can not see the field `isManager` w.r.t the user.

I have triend adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.userLogin'` in settings.py.

Edit 1:
I have added `admin.site.register(userLogin)` in admin.py

Edit 2:
I am able to create the flag and I have got a table. If I set the flag as true then I can see an entry to the table. But If I do not select the flag(i.e. False) I can not see an entry in the table.

Comment: Did you add userLogin model to your django admin?

Comment: Yes, I have added `admin.site.register(userLogin)` in admin page. I still can not see the flag in my admin page of user.

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you need to do this?  Django already includes the field is_staff in the default user model, which might be what you need anyway, unless you need to make a delineation between staff and managers.

Comment: I need the flag for another purpose I have updated the question with edit2. Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done will only create a new model table in your database that has a foreign key to the user table.  That table will be hidden from your admin until you register it in some way.  So you either need to register that table separately in the admin, or you need to create a Django inline admin class for this and reference it from the inlines variable of your User admin.

If you go the AUTH_USER_MODEL route in your settings, then you are overriding the original Django user model, so that means that you would not need this separate model with a One-To-One relation to it.  Use either method but not both.

Comment: I can now see the flag while I am adding the new user through admin after adding the Inline model. But, I can not see the changes in the Postgres database. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you add a new entry to the default user table, that will not automatically create a corresponding entry in your linked table.  You need to either modify the save method of the default user table so that it creates an entry in your linked table if one does not exist when it is called, or you need to create a hook that does the same thing.  Or you need to write your views such that you anticipate not every user entry having a corresponding userLogin entry and plan accordingly.

Comment: I can see the username and password going into the user table. But the newly created flag is not visible in the database. How to make them write into my database? Can you please send me a link to do this?